# Statistics - proportion of fish types

Tags: statistics

A fish survey is done to see if the proportion of fish types is consistent with previous years. Suppose, the 3 types of fish recorded: parrotfish, grouper, tang are historically in a 5:3:4 proportion

```
    Type of Fish     
Parrotfish  Grouper Tang
```

observed    53  22  49

I know i need to do a Chi square test, but how do I find the expected ?

Answer (score 0):

The expected, based on 5:3:4 proportions, are (5/12)*124, (3/12)*124, and (4/12)*124. The 124 is 53+22+49.